# Update text without killing href

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the text in the following HTML, what is now 1050.

```
<h2 class="g1 RightText" id="commandCount"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Commands")">1050</a></h2>
```

I have tried the following, but these remove the href link:

```
$("#commandCount").text(commandCount);
$("#commandCount").html(commandCount);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Adapt your selector in order to get the anchor element that's inside the div:

```
$("#commandCount a").text(commandCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're selecting the entire `<h2>` when you need to set focus to the `<a>`

Like this:

```
   $("#commandCount a").html(commandCount);
```

OR

```
   $("h2 a").html(commandCount);
```